# web store security

Tags: asp.net, web, c#-2.0

Imagine I have a web store, www.xpto.com, and the users must  login to buy my products. The products are in a folder www.xpto.com/apps. How can I prevent thwe user with or without login to directly access content in this folder? This site use c# and asp.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the contents of the folder. If it's other .aspx files, it's pretty easy to set up the [ASP.NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) provider for basic authentication and authorization. It's *not* as complicated as it may seem. :)

For different file types (.pdf, .xml, .jpg, etc.), you can move the files to App_Data (or something similar, outside the scope of the website) and implement a download handler, which checks for permissions before transferring the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have show me the way. The problem is to let the cliente make the download after pay, but not without pay. So I will use a download handler. Thanks again, it's important to me.